# DataPager not working properly with Listview

Tags: asp.net, listview, datapager

its the html of my aspx page

```
   <asp:ListView ID="lstviewInvoiceReport" runat="server">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table style="font-size: medium; font-family: Times New Roman">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Date
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Biller
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Customer
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Total
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Owing
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Paid
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                </tr>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDate"><%#Eval("InvoiceDate") %></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblBillerName"><%#Eval("BillerName") %></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCustName"><%#Eval("CustName") %></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTotal"><%#Eval("InvoiceTotal") %></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblOwing"><%#Eval("InvoiceOwing") %></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    <br />
    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="lstviewInvoiceReport"
        PageSize="2">
        <Fields>
            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False"
                ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
            <asp:NumericPagerField />
            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowLastPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False"
                ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DataPager>
```

and in code behind :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        dt = objBllinvoice.GetInvoiceStatement(6, 3, "20120404", "20120407");
        lstviewInvoiceReport.DataSource = dt;
        lstviewInvoiceReport.DataBind();
    }
}
```

I am binding listview with datatable its working fine but when I'm paginating listview
a) I need to click double each button to make it work.
b) data inside listview is not updating according to pagination.

Please help me in this situation. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When you use a datapager you have to data bind in PreRender. You're currently databinding in Page_Load

Comment: Ok thanks raynjamin, please update my reputation so that I can post more answers.

Comment: Hi raynjamin, pls uplift your vote to this question thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to put bind your data in `PagePropertiesChanged` Event like this:

```
protected void lstviewInvoiceReport_PagePropertiesChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BindData();
        }
```